# "require 'capybara/rails'" gives "uninitialized constant Rack::Builder"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I've been using cucumber in my app, which is a rails 2.2.2 app running in ruby 1.8.6 (upgrading isn't an option right now).  Cucumber's been fine, now i'm trying to use Capybara.  I've installed the `capybara (1.1.1)` gem and put the line `require 'capybara/rails'` in my `features/support/env.rb file`.

Now, when i run cucumber, i get this error:

```
Using the default profile...
uninitialized constant Rack::Builder (NameError)
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:445:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:77:in `const_missing'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/capybara-1.1.1/lib/capybara/rails.rb:4
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
/home/max/work/charanga/elearn_container/elearn/features/support/env.rb:10
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/cucumber-1.1.1/bin/cucumber:14
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/bin/cucumber:19
```

Here's the erroring file:

```
#/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/capybara-1.1.1/lib/capybara/rails.rb
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.app = Rack::Builder.new do
  map "/" do
    if Rails.version.to_f >= 3.0
      run Rails.application  
    else # Rails 2
      use Rails::Rack::Static
      run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
    end
  end
end.to_app

Capybara.asset_root = Rails.root.join('public')
Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = Rails.root.join('tmp/capybara')
```

So, line 4 is creating the error with the `Rack::Builder.new` line.  But, why?  Any ideas?  I have the Rack gem installed already.

thanks, max

Comment: Having a similiar problem, as soon as i add in spec/spec_helper.rb the line require 'capybara/rails' i get the error message '/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:445:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Rack::Builder (NameError)'

Comment: Uggrading to 1.8.7 Isn't an option, or to 1.9/2.0? It might solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `require 'rack/builder'` before the `require 'capybara/rails'`in `features/support/env.rb`. Rails versions lower than 2.3 don't use Rack internally and thus Rack::Builder will not be loaded like capybara seems to be assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the cucumber-rails gem?

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara says, either use the gem or, if your're not using rails, put both these lines in:

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
Capybara.app = MyRackApp
```

Comment: This is not a cucumber test runner, hence this answer didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
  gem install rack

  require 'rack' # in features/support/env.rb before every require
```

Rack::Builder is defined in rack library.

Comment: @Paul, Rack::Builder is defined in rack library.